# Check for length, then check that value is only numeric-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am attempting to do field validation on 3 textboxes (phone number). Ideally, I only want to validate in case any of the three boxes contain a value. Otherwise, no errors should be generated. Additionally, in the case that any values are placed in the textboxes I want to make sure these are only numeric.

The scenarios go as followed...

1.user enters nothing into any of the boxes: nothing happens 
2.user enters "12" into box #1, "222" into box #2, and "4444" into box #3: this results in an incomplete number. Validate.
3.user enters a value of valid length. EX: "11j" "222" "1222": this isn't a valid value, as it contains a letter. Validate.

my current solution works somewhat. Except that it does not allow user to leave any of the fields blank (scenario 1 is not valid). How can i fix this?

Validation:

```
$("#editArea,#editPrefix,#editSuffix").blur(function () {
        var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var phone = $("#editArea").val() + $("#editSuffix").val() + $("#editPrefix").val();
        var area=$("#editArea").val();
        var suffix=$("#editSuffix").val();
        var prefix=$("#editPrefix").val();
        if (phone.length > 0 && phone.length < 10||!regex.test(area)==true||!regex.test(suffix)==true||!regex.test(prefix)==true) {
            $("#editPhoneError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The number must be a numeric 10 digit value </font>');
            $("#editArea").addClass("validation");
            $("#editPrefix").addClass("validation");
            $("#editSuffix").addClass("validation");
        }
        else {
            $("#editPhoneError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
            $("#editArea").removeClass("validation");
            $("#editPrefix").removeClass("validation");
            $("#editSuffix").removeClass("validation");
        }
        $("#btnSave").prop("disabled", ($(":input.validation").length > 0));
    });   
}
```

Markup:

```
 <div>
 <input id="editArea" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editArea" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Area" depends />
 </div>
 <div>
 <input id="editPrefix" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editSuffix')" name="editPrefix" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Prefix" depends />
  </div>
  <div>
  <input id="editSuffix" maxlength="4" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editSuffix" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Suffix" depends />
  </div>
  <span style="margin-left:-208px; margin-top:50px;" id="editPhoneError" value="0"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add proper brackets between the logical operations in your if statement. Validation may cause unexpected results otherwise

Comment: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
if (phone.length > 0 && phone.length < 10||!regex.test(area)==true
       ||!regex.test(suffix)==true||!regex.test(prefix)==true) {
```

with:

```
if (area.length > 0 && suffix.length > 0 && prefix.length > 0 &&
       (phone.length < 10 || !regex.test(phone)) {
```

Note that the `||` part needs these additional parentheses, as otherwise the preceding `&&` operators take precedence.

Also, note the simplification of the `regex` test, which you can just apply to `phone` instead of the individual parts.

#### Other ideas for improvement

You actually don't have to check the whole phone number, it suffices to only check the current input value (against the `maxlength` property), and leave the presence of the `validation` class on the other input fields unaltered. On the other hand, you should validate all three fields when the page loads, which you can do with `trigger()`.

It is better to avoid HTML manipulation when possible, and in that respect you could include the error message in the original HTML, and just hide/show it.

The opposite test for numericals is easier: `/\D/` tests for the presence of any non-digit character.

It is more standard to handle the `change` event, instead of the `blur` event.

Here is a snippet that incorporates those ideas:

```js
$(function () {
  $('input.phone').change(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    // Only check current input:
    var err = v.length > 0 && (v.length < +$(this).attr('maxlength') || /\D/.test(v));
    // ...and only set the validation class on/off for current input
    $(this).toggleClass("validation", err);
    // Count if any has this class, so to show the message and disable the button
    err = $(".validation").length > 0;
    // Leave the message in place, just hide/show it
    $('#editPhoneError').toggleClass('show', err);
    $("#btnSave").prop("disabled", err);
  }).trigger('change'); // trigger at page load
});
```

```css
.phone { width:70px; }
.error { color: #c00; visibility: hidden }
.validation { border: 3px solid #e00 }
.show { visibility: visible }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input maxlength="3" class="phone" name="editArea" type="text" value="" depends />
<input maxlength="3" class="phone" name="editPrefix" type="text" value="" depends />
<input maxlength="4" class="phone" name="editSuffix" type="text" value="" depends />
<div id="editPhoneError" class="error">The number must be a numeric 10 digit value</div>
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do sth like:

JS

```
$(".phone-validation").blur(function () {
        var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var phone = this.value;
        if (phone.length > 0 && phone.length < this.getAttribute("maxlength") && !regex.test(phone)) {
            $("#editPhoneError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The number must be a numeric 10 digit value </font>');
            $(this).addClass("validation");
        }
        else {
            $("#editPhoneError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
            $(this).removeClass("validation");
        }
        $("#btnSave").prop("disabled", ($(":input.validation").length > 0));
    });   
}
```

Markup:

```
 <div>
 <input class="phone-validation" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editArea" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Area" depends />
 </div>
 <div>
 <input class="phone-validation" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editSuffix')" name="editPrefix" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Prefix" depends />
  </div>
  <div>
  <input class="phone-validation" maxlength="4" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editSuffix" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Suffix" depends />
  </div>
  <span style="margin-left:-208px; margin-top:50px;" id="editPhoneError" value="0"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Which is exactly what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `class` instead of `id` to make this form more scalable.  I've simplified your jQuery a bit and this seems to work well:

https://jsfiddle.net/rh19hfyu/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input class="phone" id="editArea" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editArea" type="text" />
</div>

<div>
 <input class="phone" id="editPrefix" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editSuffix')" name="editPrefix" type="text" />
</div>

<div>
 <input class="phone" id="editSuffix" maxlength="4" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editSuffix" type="text" />
</div>

 <span style="color:#cc0000; display:none;" id="editPhoneError" value="0">The number must be a numeric 10 digit value</span>
```

**JS**

```
  $(function() {

    $(".phone").on("blur", function () {
      var regex = /^[0-9]+$/,
          error = $("#editPhoneError"),
          phone = "";

      $(".phone").each(function() {
        phone = phone + $(this).val();
      });

      if (phone.length > 0) {
        //validate
        if(!regex.test(phone)) {
            error.show();
        }
        else {
            error.hide();
        }
      }
    });   

  });
```